# How to compare two auto complete text view by using If condition

Tags: java, android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I created two arrays in that stored two array of string values now I want to compare by using if condition please help me.

**I did like this....**

```
String[] source={"Chennai","Bangalore","Hyderabad"};

String[] destination={"Chennai","Bangalore","Hyderabad"};

if(source[0] == "Chennai" && destination[2] == "Hyderabad") {
      //Here i want to print some thing  
}
```

Comment: now I want to compare by using if condition - what do you want to compare. what is string here?

Comment: what you need to compare? is it by index of arrays of just hardcoding values?

Comment: Try using 
 String[] destination={"Chennai","Bangalore","Hyderabad"};
        String[] source={"Chennai","Bangalore","Hyderabad"};
        if(source[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Chennai") && destination[2].equalsIgnoreCase("hyderabad"))
        {
/*Add your code*/
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(source[0].equals("Chennai") && destination[2].equals("Hyderabad"))
  {
      Here i want to print some thing  
  }
```